# Hide filter options in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I'm using iframes to display charts from Pentaho Console 5.3.0.0.213.  I have some filters set up (basically just to display certain account IDs), and I can't figure out if there's a way to lock that down. I don't want users to be able to change the filters.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are your charts made by Pentaho CDE? What component do you use for filters?